# Handling reserved keywords depends on the lexical definition

Tags: keyword, rascal, reserved

My question is about handling reserved keywords in Rascal syntax definitions. Take the following Rascal module, which has been derived from the on-line documentation:

```
module Test
// Taken from http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Declarations/SyntaxDefinition/SyntaxDefinition.html

start syntax Top = Identifier | ReservedKeyword;

layout MyLayout = [\t\n\ \r\f]*;

// Is OK, parse(#Top,"if") succeeds, parse(#Identifier,"if") fails
lexical Identifier = [a-z] !<< [a-z]+ !>> [a-z] \ MyKeywords;

// Goes wrong, parse(#Top,"if") fails, parse(#Identifier,"if") succeeds, 
// so "if" is not exluded
//lexical Identifier = [a-z0-9] !<< [a-z][a-z0-9]* !>> [a-z0-9] \ MyKeywords;

keyword MyKeywords = "if" | "then" | "else" | "fi";

syntax ReservedKeyword = "if" | "then" | "else" | "fi";
```

The point is that the reserved keywords construction `\ MyKeywords` only works if the lexical is defined as `[a-z] !<< [a-z]+ !>> [a-z]`. If the lexical becomes slightly more complicated `[a-z0-9] !<< [a-z][a-z0-9]* !>> [a-z0-9]` then the keywords are no longer excluded.

What do I do wrong here? How can I exclude keywords in case of identifiers like `[a-z][a-z0-9]*`?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is that iuxtapositioning of symbols such as `[a-z]` next to `[a-z0-9]+` binds less strong than the `\` operator and the `!>>` operator.

So here we are reserving `MyKeywords` only from the tail `[a-z0-9]+` of the identifier:

```
lexical Identifier = [a-z] !<< [a-z][a-z0-9]+ \ MyKeywords;
```

to fix this, you can add brackets to remove `MyKeywords` from the entire sequence:

```
lexical Identifier = [a-z] !<< ([a-z][a-z0-9]+) \ MyKeywords;
```

and then you can add the restriction again:

```
lexical Identifier = [a-z] !<< ([a-z][a-z0-9]+) \ MyKeywords !>> [a-z];
```

or like so, equivalently:

```
lexical Identifier = [a-z] !<< ([a-z][a-z0-9]+) !>> [a-z] \ MyKeywords;
```